Duplicate log entries google cloud logging, opentelemetry.sdk python
I am parsing txt files that contain the logs of GitHub Workflow Jobs/Steps and send them to google cloud. I am using below code :
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import LoggerProvider, LoggingHandler
import dateutil.parser as dp

def get_logger(resource, name):

    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    client.setup_logging()

    logger = logging.getLogger(str(name))
    logger.handlers.clear()
    logger_provider = LoggerProvider(resource=resource)
    handler = LoggingHandler(level=logging.NOTSET, logger_provider=logger_provider)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

resource_attributes ={"github.source": "github-exporter","workflow_run_id": GHA_RUN_ID}

resource_log = Resource(attributes=resource_attributes)
job_logger = get_logger(resource_log, "job_logger")

with open ("./logs/log1.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        try:
            line_to_add = line[29:-1].strip()
            len_line_to_add = len(line_to_add)
            timestamp_to_add = line[0:23]
            if len_line_to_add > 0:
                # Convert ISO 8601 to timestamp
                try:
                    parsed_t = dp.isoparse(timestamp_to_add)
                except ValueError as e:
                    print("Line does not start with a date. Skip for now")
                    continue
                unix_timestamp = parsed_t.timestamp()*1000

                extra_data = {
                "log.timestamp":unix_timestamp,
                "log.time":timestamp_to_add,
                }


                if line_to_add.lower().startswith("##[debug]"):
                    job_logger._log(level=logging.DEBUG,msg=line_to_add,extra=extra_data,args="")
                else:
                    job_logger._log(level=logging.INFO,msg=line_to_add,extra=extra_data,args="")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error exporting log line ERROR: ", e)

Result is to have multiple entries of the same message with only difference the insertId of each message.
For instance, logs entry looks like in text file
Fri, 19 Apr 2024 12:16:29 GMT   Ubuntu
Fri, 19 Apr 2024 12:16:29 GMT   22.04.4
Fri, 19 Apr 2024 12:16:29 GMT   LTS

And here is what I see in Google Cloud Logs Explorer
Screenshot from Google Cloud Logs Explorer
I have read
Duplicate log entries google cloud logging on stackdriver in google cloud function using python
and
Duplicate log entries with Google Cloud Stackdriver logging of Python code on Kubernetes Engine
regarding
the client.setup_logging method sets up 2 handlers, a normal logging.StreamHandler and also a GCP-specific handler

But I cannot understand how I could apply this with opentelemetry.sdk._logs package.
Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

How, exactly, is this code called?  msg=line_to_add suggests that this is not the actual full code, because that variable does not exist.

Here is the called code https://github.com/newrelic-experimental/gha-new-relic-exporter/blob/e04acfe37bbfeee14f6f4f3f45d37ce73d38ff1f/src/exporter.py#L138-L166
In the original code the logs are sent to new relic, but I am working on a solution that will sent the logs into google cloud logs

Don't make us click an external link to see the code.  The full code should be posted here, directly in the question.  If that would be too long, it's your job to make a short example that still demonstrates the problem.

Updated my code snippet. Though I don't believe the code was missing is part of the problem.

Another explanation is that logs/log1.txt contains duplicate lines.  You haven't shown us a complete example with the actual contents of that file, so we can only guess.
